# Wildfly: change smtp resource and mail session from JSF application

Tags: jsf, wildfly

There is a simple way to create a JSF page to change smtp configuration and mail session in Wildfly 9?

I know that i can do that in CLI, so i can call a bash script to set the values, as:

```
/socket-binding-group=standard-sockets/remote-destination-outbound-socket-binding=$smtp:add(host=$host, port=$port)
/subsystem=mail/mail-session=$name:add(jndi-name="$jndi", from="$from", debug=$debug)
/subsystem=mail/mail-session=$name/server=smtp:add(outbound-socket-binding-ref=$smtp, ssl=$ssl, username=$user, password=$pass)
```

but i'am searching for a simpler way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wildfly has also a [HTTP management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/The+HTTP+management+API) and [native management API](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY9/The+native+management+API).

HTTP API example:

```
$ curl --digest  http://localhost:9990/management --header "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"operation":"write-attribute", "name":"default-timeout", "value":"600", "address":["subsystem","transactions"]}' -u admin
Enter host password for user 'admin':
{"outcome" : "success", "response-headers" : {"operation-requires-reload" : true, "process-state" : "reload-required"}}
```